# Applying lm() on a data frame

Tags: r, lm

Can anyone please explain how `lm()` works if we simply pass a data frame as an argument.For example, I am running `lm(split(mtcars,mtcars$cyl)[[1]])`. How does lm interpret this and what does the output mean?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it is taking the first variable as dependent.  You can check `lm(mtcars)` and `lm(mpg ~., mtcars)`

Answer (score 0):

lm is short for linear model and is one function to build a linear model around your data. 
A linear model looks like this:

```
y = a x1 + b x2 + c x3 + e
```

The output repeats the given input and then displays the model-coefficients as `Coefficients:`
So you might just put the outputted coefficients into the upper equation or store it in a variable and get the model's "performance" with summary().